# How do you run a Java class from another class?

Tags: java

I am working on a project for school. at this point i'm just going over board, I would like to run the class bookstoreCreditPersonal if none of the following conditions are true, but I cant get it to work. any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bookstoreCreditPersonal {
    public static void main(Object o) {
        String studentNamePers;
        String userType;
    double studentGPAPers;
    double bookstoreCreditPers;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter 'S' if you are the student, 'T' if you are the teacher, or 'P' if you are the Parent: ");
    userType = input.nextLine();

    if (userType.equals("S")) {
        System.out.println("Greetings student...");
        Scanner Sinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your(The students) first and last name :");
        studentNamePers = input.nextLine();

        Scanner SSinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your(The student's) GPA :");
        studentGPAPers = input.nextDouble();

        bookstoreCreditPers = studentGPAPers * 10;

        System.out.println(studentNamePers + ", your GPA is " + studentGPAPers + ", and you have an available bookstore credit of $" + bookstoreCreditPers);
    } else if (userType.equals("T")) {
        System.out.println("Teacher");
    } else if (userType.equals("P")) {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lets try that again, one character, in capital form only please.");
        //created a class that reruns this class
        runClassBSCP.call(null);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the class runClassBSCP:

```
public class runClassBSCP {
    public void call() {
         bookstoreCreditPersonal.main(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: You cannot run a class. You can instantiate an object of a class or you can call static methods of that class or instance method on an object of that class.

Comment: So, you basically want to do `main` again from the top when the user made a bad input?

Comment: You class names should begin with an UPPER CASE letter... Also, instead of `runClassBSCP.call(null);` why do not call `main(null);` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate/create an object of the class. Then you can call the desired method with the object.

```
runClassBSCP bscp = new runClassBSCP();
bscp.call();
```

Also, your class names should always start with an uppercase letter: `RunClassBSCP`, rather than `runClassBSCP'. For more info, check out [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).